# the method in type not applicable for the arguments

Tags: java, parameters, compiler-errors, arguments, boolean

I am getting this error message:

2 errors found:

> Error: The method determineTaxRate(double) in the type PayCalculator
>   is not applicable for the arguments ()
>
> Error: The method calculateNetPay(double, double) in the type
>   PayCalculator is not applicable for the arguments ()

Can you tell me what to do to fix this?

```
public class PayCalculator
{
    private double hourlyRate;
    private double hoursWorked;

     /**
     * Two parameter constructor
     * Add hourlyRate and hoursWorked
     * @param the hourly rate
     * @param the hours worked
     */
    public PayCalculator(double aHourlyRate, double aHoursWorked)
    {
        hourlyRate = aHourlyRate;
        hoursWorked = aHoursWorked;
    }

    /**
    * sets the hourly rate
    * @return hourlyRate
    */ 
    public void setHourlyRate(double aHourlyRate)
    {
        hourlyRate = aHourlyRate;
    }

    /**
    * gets the hourly rate
    * @param hourlyRate
    */
    public double getHourlyRate()
    {
        return hourlyRate;
    }

    /**
    * sets the hours worked
    * @return hoursWorked
    */ 
    public void setHoursWorked(double aHoursWorked)
    {
        hoursWorked = aHoursWorked;
    }

    /**
    * gets the hours worked
    * @param hours worked
    */
    public double getHoursWorked()
    {
        return hoursWorked;
    }



    public boolean workedOvertime()
    {
        if (hoursWorked > 40)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public double numHoursOvertime()
    {
        if (hoursWorked > 40)
        {
            return hoursWorked - 40;
        }
        else 
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public double calculateGrossPay()
    {
        if (hourlyRate  <= 10.25)
        {
            if (hourlyRate <= 40)
                return hourlyRate * hoursWorked;
        }
        else 
        {  
            double grossPay = ((40 * hourlyRate) + ((hourlyRate * 2) * hoursWorked - 40));
            return grossPay;
        }

        if (hoursWorked <= 60)
        {
            return hourlyRate * hoursWorked;
        }
        else
        {
            return 60 * hourlyRate;
        }
    }

    public double determineTaxRate(double grossPay)
    {
        if (grossPay >= 800)
        {
            double tax = 0;
            tax = grossPay * 0.37;
            return tax;
        }
        else if ( grossPay >= 400)
        {
            double tax = 0;
            tax = grossPay * 0.22;
            return tax;
        }
        else
        {
            double tax = 0;
            tax = grossPay * 0.12;
            return tax;
        }
    }

    public double calculateNetPay(double grossPay, double tax)
    {
        double calculateNetPay = grossPay - tax;
        return calculateNetPay;
    }

    public void printData()
    {
        System.out.println("Hours Worked: " + hoursWorked);
        System.out.println("Hourly rate: " + hourlyRate);
        System.out.println("Number of hours of overtime worked: " + numHoursOvertime());
        System.out.println("Worked overtime? " + workedOvertime());
        System.out.println("Gross pay: " + calculateGrossPay());
        System.out.println("Tax Rate: " + determineTaxRate());
        System.out.println("Net Pay: " + calculateNetPay());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are calling

```
determineTaxRate()
```

But your method is defined as this:

```
public double determineTaxRate(double grossPay)
{
```

Same with your other error. You need to pass a `double` to the method. Such as this:

```
determineTaxRate(calculateGrossPay())
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified arguments for the methods which you are calling from `printData()` method, for example:

```
System.out.println("Net Pay: " + calculateNetPay());
```

You are calling `calculateNetPay()` with 0 arguments, where as in your method defnition you have specified, it needs 2 double arguments.

```
public double calculateNetPay(double grossPay, double tax) { ... }
```

Same applies for other errors you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

your method defined with one argument.But you are not passing any parameters.

For calculateNetPay() also you are doing the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

you have declared your method like this :

```
public double determineTaxRate(double grossPay)
```

and later invoke it like this :

```
determineTaxRate()
```

obviously,you have missed a parameter when invoking the method

fix this by  determineTaxRate(someDoubleVar)

Comment: i add this to the print data?

Comment: to everywhere you invoke this method like  : System.out.println("Tax Rate: " + determineTaxRate(someDoubleVar));